# Chrome freezes after exiting full screen mode in Netflix

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome, freeze, netflix

So Ubuntu has recently announced the support of Netflix using Chrome v37+.
I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 with Chrome 37.0.2062.120 (64-bit), and I have a problem specifically with Netflix.

When I exit the full screen mode after watching a video, and either press the little red cross to close the tab, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> or middle-click on the tab, Chrome freezes and I get a prompt to close the application because it stopped responding...

Anyone else having this problem? Any idea on how to diagnose it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable in Google Chrome the "Use hardware acceleration when available" and check if you have a better experience. It's not a solution, but at least a workaround. It did the trick for me.

Comment: Tried both hardware acceleration disabled and enabled and still happens to me,